# ESP8266 too many argument to function

Tags: nodemcu, blynk

My project uses ESP8226 to allow:
    1) user to set an alarm.
    2) after 20 sec of the alarm ringing, it will notify to phone via blynk app using motion sensor.
    3) after 40 sec it will turn off sensor and will not send notification 
       again.
There are two problems that I have:

- Got error with coding (digitalRead(nilai_sensor, LOW);) "too many arguments to function 'int digitalRead(uint8_t)"
- I need help with coding for turn off the sensor and 
  will not nofify again.

Below is my Arduino code:

```
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <WidgetRTC.h>
BlynkTimer timer;
WidgetRTC rtc;
WidgetLED led1(V10);
// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "a7d4522186464dd297870f2ab8e53250";

// Your WiFi credentials.
// Set password to "" for open networks.
char ssid[] = "NabiL";
char pass[] = "limaringgitlimapuluhsen";
int flag = 0;
int buzzer = 12;
int motor = 13;
int sensor = 4;



int saat;
int on_delay;
int off_delay;
int ok_delay;

int get1 = 0;
int get2 = 0;
int nilai_sensor = 0;

void blinkLedWidget()
{
  if (led1.getValue()) {
    led1.off();
    Serial.println("LED on V1: off");
  } else {
    led1.on();
    Serial.println("LED on V1: on");
  }
}

void clockDisplay()
{
  // You can call hour(), minute(), ... at any time
  // Please see Time library examples for details

  String currentTime = String(hour()) + ":" + minute() + ":" + second();
  String currentDate = String(day()) + "/" + month() + "/" + year();
  Serial.print("Current time: ");
  Serial.print(currentTime);
  Serial.print("Current Time: ");
  Serial.print(currentDate);
  Serial.println();

  // Send time to the App
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V1, currentTime);
  // Send date to the App
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V2, currentDate);
}

BLYNK_CONNECTED() {
  // Synchronize time on connection
  rtc.begin();
}
BLYNK_WRITE(V5) // Timer
{
  Serial.println(param.asStr());


  if (param.asInt())
  {
    on_delay = saat + 20;  //20Saat
    off_delay = saat + 10;  //10Saat
    ok_delay = saat + 40;  //40Saat

    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor, HIGH);
  }
}
BLYNK_WRITE(V6) // Timer
{
  Serial.println(param.asStr());


  if (param.asInt())
  {
    on_delay = saat + 20;  //20Saat
    off_delay = saat + 10;  //10Saat
    ok_delay = saat + 40;  //40Saat

    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor, HIGH);
  }
}
BLYNK_WRITE(V0){
  Serial.println(param.asStr());


  if (param.asInt())
  {

    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor, HIGH);

  }
  else

  {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor, LOW);

  }
}
BLYNK_WRITE(V12){
  Serial.println(param.asStr());


  if (param.asInt())
  {

    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  }
  else

  {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  }
}
BLYNK_WRITE(V13){
  Serial.println(param.asStr());


  if (param.asInt())
  {

    digitalWrite(motor, HIGH);
  }
  else

  {

    digitalWrite(motor, LOW);
  }
}
void setup()
{
  // Debug console
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  setSyncInterval(10 * 60); // Sync interval in seconds (10 minutes)

  // Display digital clock every 1 seconds
  timer.setInterval(1000L, clockDisplay);
timer.setInterval(1000L, blinkLedWidget);
  // Setup notification button on pin D1



  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT);


}
void loop()
{
  saat = millis() / 1000;

  if(saat == off_delay)
  {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor, LOW);
  }



   if(saat == on_delay)
  {
    Serial.println("Time Up");
    get1 = 1;
  }

     if(get1 == 1)
    {
     Serial.println("Program Sensor");

   nilai_sensor = digitalRead(sensor); 

    if(nilai_sensor == HIGH)
    {
      Serial.println("Still sleeping");
     Blynk.notify("Still sleeping");

    //delay(5000);
   }
  }


if(saat == ok_delay)
  { 
    Serial.println("Shut Down Sensor");
    get2 = 1;
  }
 if(get2 == 1)
  {
    Serial.println("turn off Sensor");
    nilai_sensor = digitalRead(sensor);
   digitalRead(nilai_sensor, LOW);

  }


  Blynk.run();
  timer.run(); // Initiates BlynkTimer

}
```

Comment: how do you want to turn off a sensor over the pin you use to read it? simply don't read it

Answer (score 2):

The function [`digitalRead()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalread/) has only one argument: the digital pin that you want to know the state (*high* or *low*).

You must change the use of this function, to something like this:

```
int state = digitalRead(nilai_sensor)

if (state == low) {
    //do something here
}
```

Hope you can find helpfull :D